# How to run long running task with aws lamba with cloudwatch event

Tags: cron, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am running a cron which runs everyday,  which connects to database(x),and export data from from x database to y database and then deletes that data from x database. Entire execution takes way more than 5 min.

I am thinking to use lambda with cloudwatch event but lambda has execution limit 5 min. I had thought of running the query in batch and run lambda multiple times, however i donot know how many times lambda should run. Is there some way i can do to this task with lambda or are there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using some AWS container service (ECS/EKS/Fargate) to execute an "export container": for example ECS also supports scheduled execution:

"You can run Amazon ECS tasks on a cron-like schedule using CloudWatch Events rules and targets." see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html

Using this you do not hit the 5min limit in lambda and still only pay for the time your container is running (if set up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about implementing your cronjob with `StepFunctions`?
A possible solution to your problem is to process your job in small batches. And between your batches check the current execution time. If the execution time is above a specific threshold you terminate your lambda, and your step function launches another one until your whole data is exported.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the time remaining in context, which is called `getRemainingTimeInMillis()`. Keep an eye on it and recursively invoke the same lambda with a marker when time remaining gets low. Rinse and repeat.

Danger: You can easily DoS yourself doing this incorrectly. Don't panic if you do, but you will probably have to delete the AWS Lambda function and re-upload it to stop the infinite loop!